# Can I enforce scalar types to be initialized to zero by int{}?

Tags: c++, initialization, default-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
template<class T>
void someFun() {
    T t;
    // stuff with t
}
```

Here I can be sure that if `T` is a default-constructible `struct` or `class` then `t` should be initialized to its default value.

However, if `T` is, for example, an `int`, then it will be uninitialized here. Well, the intuitive "default initialization" for an `int` should mean that it should be initialized to zero.

What I'm looking for is a way to call the default constructor for `T` if `T` is of a class type and to initialize it to zero if it is a scalar type.

Will this work?

```
template<class T>
void someFun() {
    T t{};
    // stuff with t
}
```

AFAIK in the above example the default contructor for `T` will be called if its a class type, but can I be sure that it will be zero if it is an `int` or another scalar type?

Comment: I'm 99% sure the answer is yes. At the very least, I know that `int foo = {}` initializes it to 0. Searching for a source...

Comment: "Will this work?" Well, did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: @DimChtz That doesn't work so well with C++. It may well appear to work, but not actually work

Comment: AFAIK, `T t{};` guarantees that the value will be default-constructed and initialized, so long as a default-construction exists for that type, which it does for all fundamental types.

Comment: @DimChtz https://ideone.com/weZQN4 Yes I did try it HOWEVER this is C++ for sake, it is perfectly plausible to assume that unless I have a guarantee it will work 99% of times and make `t` contain some garbage in this 1% of times.

Comment: [Yes it's guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

Comment: Related, maybe possible duplicate of? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11164394/1896169

Comment: @Justin Make an answer from this cppreference link, so I can accept it :)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14259602/1896169

Answer (score 3):

For scalar types `{}` intializer triggers so-called *value-initialization*. And, for scalar types value-initialization leads to zero-initialization. So, yes, it will zero-initialize objects of scalar types.

For class types with default constructor it also triggers value-initialization, which leads to default-initialization (class with user-provided default constructor) or zero-initialization (class without user-provided or deleted default constructor).

So, it appears to do what you want it do do in all cases you mentioned.

Comment: I think the question wants something that works for non-scalar types too, which this still does in most cases.

Comment: Aggregate initialization differs as usual: for class types which are aggregates there is no zero-initialization of the whole object and no constructor invocation; instead, each non-static data member without a brace-or-equal-initializer is initialized as if by `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Justin already dug up [the correct reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) in the comments (it's called zero-initialization), so yes, this works for all class and non-class types. Not just integral types, but also bools, floating-point types and pointers.

It doesn't work for `someFun<void>()` though, but I'd say that function is devoid of fun.

Comment: The general term is “[value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)”, which does zero-initialization for fundamental types. This syntax might do [aggregate-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) or [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) for some types instead, In any case, it should probably do what you want.