# Value-initialization in pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am quite ignorant of C++, so I hope I have identified my problem correctly.

I am maintaining Python bindings based on *pybind11* of some old project and I stumbled upon a class that has what I think it's called a constructor defined via *value-initialization* - see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164394/constructor-initialization-list-with-empty-initialization)) and I am trying to understand how to write the constructor on the pybind11 side.

The code looks like this,

```
class MyClass {

public:

    MyClass() : a (""),
                b(0xFF),
                c(0),
                d("") { }

    ~MyClass() { }

    std::string a;
    char b;
    uint64_t c;
    std::string d;

.....

}
```

and what I have on the pybind side is basically just a series of `def_property_readonly` which is sufficient to access the attributes from existing objects, but now I want to create a new one from scratch.

Is this possible?

To be clearer, the following does not work

```
.def(py::init<const std::string &, const char, const uint64_t,
                    const std::string &>())
```

resulting in a compilation error like "error: no matching constructor for initialization", because of course the init function is empty and the initialized attributes are after the colon symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you pybind11 can't find this constructor to expose:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string & a_, const char b_, const uint64_t c_,
                const std::string & d_)
: a(a_), b(b_), c(c_), d(d_) {}
```

Either you'll need to add such a constructor to `MyClass` (recommended), or expose the default constructor you have already defined via pybind:

```
.def(py::init<>())
```

Keep in mind, these solutions will do two different things, the first will allow you to construct `MyClass` from python with four arguments `my_class = MyClass("abc", 'a', 1, "abc")`, whereas the second option will allow you to default construct instances of `MyClass` from python: `my_class = MyClass()`. Decide which is suitable for your case (or implement both solutions).

Comment: Yeah, I kind of understand that in the end what I have is some kind of default constructor, so I cannot control the attribute values. Indeed if I compile the code and use the python bindings I can create an instance and see the default values, but what I want it what you say I should add, so initialize the class with the values I decide.